# UICollectionView with Sticky horizontal indicator Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uicollectionview

I want to Sticky horizontal scroll indicator for UICollectionView when I scroll back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

**UICollectionView** inherits from **UIScrollView**. There's no easy way to always show the scroll indicator. The indicator is visible while tracking is underway and fades out after tracking.

You can flash the indicators using `collectionView.flashScrollIndicators()` to show the user that they exist.

Otherwise, you can for example create a custom UICollectionView or extend UIScrollView to create your own indicators that's always visible.